# CakePHP Fully Dynamic Links

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to add a link to my layout and would like it to by dynamic.

Example:
User is on a page with controller=controller, action=index and say X params. I would like the

```
echo $this->Html->link();
```

Function to automatically append the params that were supplied without manually coding them (each action might have a different amount of params/args).

Thanks!

Comment: Erm, did you try anything? `$this->Html->link('title here');` should already give you a link to the current page. For additional parameters, you may need to mark them to `persist` in your routes. **What is your expected result?** **What did you get instead?** Read the [faq] for hints on how to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've resolved it using:

```
$this->passedArgs
```

In case it's relevant to anyone :)